# SerializeToArray protobuf not storing

Tags: c++, qt, protocol-buffers

I am very new to protobufs and attempting some simple serialising and deserialising.

```
int sizeArray        = event0.ByteSize();
QByteArray * qbArray = new QByteArray[sizeArray];

cout << "byteSizeOfEvent0:      " << sizeArray              << endl;    
cout << "preSTA size:           " << qbArray->size()        << endl;
cout << "is event0 initialized? " << event0.IsInitialized() << endl;

event0.SerializeToArray(qbArray, sizeArray);

cout << "postSTA size: " << qbArray->size() << endl;
```

produces the results

```
byteSizeOfEvent0:      48
preSTA size:           0
is event0 initialized? 1
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

The process of calling on qbArray after SerializeToArray is causing a crash, I assume due to failed writing of data. The event is initialised and appears correct when using SerializeAsString and deBugging.

I have looked at other posts who serializeToArray in the same way. Am I doing something clearly wrong?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`new QByteArray[sizeArray]` allocates an array of `sizeArray` empty `QByteArray`s, not a `sizeArray`-byte long `QByteArray`.  If you want to use `QByteArray`, this should look something like

```
int sizeArray = event0.ByteSize();
QByteArray qbArray(sizeArray, 0);

cout << "byteSizeOfEvent0:      " << sizeArray              << endl;    
cout << "preSTA size:           " << qbArray.size()         << endl;
cout << "is event0 initialized? " << event0.IsInitialized() << endl;

event0.SerializeToArray(qbArray.data(), sizeArray);

cout << "postSTA size: " << qbArray.size() << endl;
```

Note, however, that those two `size()` calls are both going to return the same thing, since `qbArray` is initialized to be `sizeArray` bytes long.

Comment: Thanks for the help!